# Como deletar diretório do armazenamento interno no Android?

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho duas funções para salvar arquivos na memoria interna do meu aplicativo, um para dados em Json e outro para Imagens.

A cada nova atualização do aplicativo, vou precisar que seja removido esses diretórios para que os arquivos novos sejam salvos no lugar dos antigos.

Segue o código que estou usando para criar e salvar os dados.

```
public static Boolean SaveJsonData(Context context, String dir, String filename, String jsondata) {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(context.getDir(dir, Context.MODE_PRIVATE), filename));
        fileOutputStream.write(jsondata.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                fileOutputStream.close();
                return true;
            } else { return false; }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Os arquivos são salvos nos diretórios:

`/data/data/br.com.meuapp.app/app_json`

`/data/data/br.com.meuapp.app/app_icones`

Como eu faço para remover esses dois diretórios com tudo que tiver dentro dele?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma resposta no stack no seguinte link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46086062/9441092

Nesta resposta tem a seguinte função:

```
   public int removeDirectory(final File folder) {
        if(folder.isDirectory() == true) {
            File[] folderContents = folder.listFiles();
            int deletedFiles = 0;
            if(folderContents.length == 0) {
                if(folder.delete()) {
                    deletedFiles++;
                    return deletedFiles;
                }
            } else if(folderContents.length > 0) {
                do {
                    File lastFolder = folder;
                    File[] lastFolderContents = lastFolder.listFiles();
                    //This while loop finds the deepest path that does not contain any other folders
                    do {
                        for(File file : lastFolderContents) {
                            if(file.isDirectory()) {
                                lastFolder = file;
                                lastFolderContents = file.listFiles();
                                break;
                            } else {
                                if(file.delete()) {
                                    deletedFiles++;
                                } else {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }//End if(file.isDirectory())
                        }//End for(File file : folderContents)
                    } while(lastFolder.delete() == false);
                    deletedFiles++;
                    if(folder.exists() == false) { return deletedFiles; }
                } while(folder.exists());
            }
        }
        else { return -1; }
         return 0;
    }
```

Achei esta função perfeita, pq não só exclui qualquer diretório, como ainda retorna o numero de registros deletados.

E para pegar o diretório que preciso deletar eu estou pegando com a seguinte linha:

`File Pathdir = context.getDir(dir, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

E por final minha função ficou assim:

```
public static int DeleteInternalFiles(Context context, String dir){
    File Pathdir = context.getDir(dir, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return removeDirectory(Pathdir);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
String path = "caminho da pasta/arquivo, etc";

boolean p = new File(path).delete();

if(p){
     Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Deletado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
     Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Erro inesperado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo pra mim, da o seguinte erro:
`
Do not hardcode "/data/"; use Context.getFilesDir().getPath() instead less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Your code should not reference the /sdcard path directly; instead use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().  Similarly, do not reference the /data/data/ path directly; it can vary in multi-user scenarios. Instead, use Context.getFilesDir().getPath().  More info:`
........
Minha duvida é exatamente em como pegar o path do diretorio para colocar numa função, tipo assim:

**MinhaClasse.DeletarDiretorio("json");** Sabe??

Comment: Consegui resolver, vou postar a resposta.